# I need to read a .mif file created by IP Core Gen in xilinx

Tags: vhdl

Here is my code:

```
library IEEE;

use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL; 
use STD.TEXTIO.ALL;

entity new1 IS

    port(data : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0)); 
end new1;

architecture Behavioral of new1 is

begin
    process 

    type my_file IS FILE OF INTEGER; 
    file data_in : my_file; 
    variable fstatus : file_open_status; 
    file_open(data_in, "c:\temp2.mif", read);

end process;

end Behavioral;
```

The code is giving error:

> "unexpected identifier"

in the command `file_open`.

Comment: Are you asking what is causing the error?

Answer (score 1):

You're process was missing a `begin`.

```
    process 
        type my_file is file of integer; 
        file data_in : my_file; 
        variable fstatus : file_open_status; 
    begin
        file_open(fstatus, data_in, "c:\temp2.mif", READ_MODE);
    end process;
```

The unexpected identifier appears to be `read`, where `READ_MODE` was expected.

You don't have to connect the `file_open_status` output for procedure `file_open`, but if you don't why did you declare it?

The form of the implicitly declared procedure `file_open` (see IEEE Std 1076-2008, 5.5.2 File operations):

```
    type FT is file of TM;
```

> where type mark TM denotes a scalar type, a record type, or a fully constrained array subtype, the following
>   operations are implicitly declared immediately following the file type declaration:
>   ...

```
procedure FILE_OPEN (Status: out FILE_OPEN_STATUS; 
                     file F: FT;  
                     External_Name: in STRING;
                     Open_Kind: in FILE_OPEN_KIND := READ_MODE);
```

Note this process as is doesn't do anything interesting.  Without a sensitivity list or an explicit wait statement it would try to open the file for read over and over again in an endless loop.

Modifying the process will at least allow the code to analyze. It still needs further work.

For the code you are displaying two of the use clauses are not needed:

```
-- use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
-- use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
```

Comment: can "textio" package be used for synthesis purpose?

Comment: actually i am working on a image watermarking project. so, i import the pixel values of the image in a .coe file using MATLAB and then convert it into .mif file usng IP core generator in Xilinx. And then i wish to open the .mif file. the contents of this file must be transfereed to an array which will be further processed. could you plz help me out in synthesizing such a circuit.?? i have synthesized rest of the circuit. i am sending u the code after the corrections u told  me. it is giving error:"read can not have such operands in this context."

Comment: library IEEE;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
library std;
use std.textio.all;  
--entity declaration
entity filehandle is
end filehandle;
architecture Behavioral of filehandle is
signal clock,endoffile : bit := '0';
signal    dataread : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal    linenumber : integer:=1; 
begin
clock <= not (clock) after 1 ns;
reading :process
file   infile    : text is in  "c:\temp2.mif";   
variable  inline    : line; variable  dataread1    : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);

Comment: begin
wait until clock = '1' and clock'event;
if (not endfile(infile)) then   
readline(infile, inline); 
read(inline, dataread1);
dataread <=dataread1;   
else
endoffile <='1';         
end if;
end process reading;
writing :
process
    file      outfile  : text is out "c:\temp3.mif";  
    variable  outline  : line;   --line number declaration  
begin
wait until clock = '0' and clock'event;
if(endoffile='0') then   
write(outline, dataread);
writeline(outfile, outline);
linenumber <= linenumber + 1;
else
null;
end if;
end process writing;
end Behavioral;

Comment: **can "textio" package be used for synthesis purpose?** Generally no.  There's a lot of system magic hidden behind the host side of a file operation. You could conceivably do something with shared memory, handshaking flags and passed commands. It wouldn't be textio. It would require a driver on the host.

Comment: It's possible to use memory initialization files to embed initialization values in bitstreams for programming FPGAs. How to do that is dependent on the particular synthesis vendor. It used to be common for them to support LPM memory models which is where **mif** comes from.

Comment: sir, could you plz suggest me some literature from which i can understand how to read/write .mif files for synthesis purpose.

Comment: See [Quartus initializing RAM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19751148/quartus-initializing-ram) and [Inferred RAM doesn't initialize in ModelSim Altera edition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23193206/inferred-ram-doesnt-initialize-in-modelsim-altera-edition) on Stackoverflow. textio work for some synthesis tool during elaboration - intializing the contents of memory.  Note Modelsim has it's own method of initializing a memory, see [modelsim_se_tut.pdf](http://cs.colby.edu/courses/S15/cs232/labs/lab01/modelsim_se_tut.pdf) Page 136 and the index.

Comment: See [Memory Initialization File (.mif)](http://www.mil.ufl.edu/4712/docs/mif_help.pdf) noting Intel hex format is more commonly supported (as per Brian's answer in [Quartus initializing RAM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19751148/quartus-initializing-ram). If you get stuck ask a new question.